# Different java version with sudo command

Tags: java, sudo

On my mac laptop

When i run the command

```
javac -version
```

I get `javac 1.8.0_161`

But when run

```
sudo javac -version
```

I get `javac 14.0.1`

Why is this happening because it is giving me issues.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable - namely JAVA_HOME and PATH.

Comment: Note that you can also e.g. check the location of the files using `which javac`.

Comment: `which javac` and `sudo which javac` hava the same output which is `/usr/bin/javac`

Comment: `which javac` won't help you as it will show you a link. You need `readlink -f $(which javac)`

Comment: @Kayaman - `$JAVA_HOME` is not relevant to what `javac -version` says.  It will be `$PATH` that is different.  Which is to be expected with `sudo`.  Mustafa - read the manual entry for `sudo` to find out how it handles the `PATH`.

Comment: @g00se - with `sudo`, I think that would need to be `sudo bash -c 'readlink -f $(which javac)'`.  You need to jump through hoops to ensure that `which` is being executed in the same context as is used by `sudo` in `sudo javac -version`.

Comment: However it is puzzling that Mustafa gets `/usr/bin/javac` both times.  It implies either that either the binary at the end of the link chain is environment sensitive (huh?!!) OR that the link chain resolves differently for the `root` user.  The latter implies there is some kind of sandboxing going on at the shell level.   (Or maybe this is just a Mac thing ...)

Comment: If your shell is not (a variant of) csh, [try `type java` instead of `which`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then) -- it might be an alias or function. Also if you've been changing your PATH, try `hash -t java` in case it's mis-cached.

Comment: *@g00se - with sudo, I think that would need to be ...* I ignored the sudo thing as I'm not convinced. For one thing, /usr/bin/javac cannot link to two different places at the same time, unless there's a very big hole in my knowledge. But, yes, of course there can be differences in other respects, such as aliases, paths and variables between environments. My recommendation, when unsure about these effects, would be to `sudo su` first then execute whatever is necessary.